# Check If a <p> element has a value in it or not

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dom-events, innerhtml

I want to check If a `<p>` element has text in it or not, using pure Javascript.

For exemple, if the element is like that: `<p></p>` I want it to return me 0, or false or null or Something like that, and If it ia like that `<p>Hello World</p>` to return me true, or the value, or 1, or Something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a reference to the `p` element (from `getElementById`, `querySelector`, or whatever), you can see if it's **completely** empty like this:

```
if (!theElement.firstChild) {
    // It's empty
}
```

(Or `theElement.childNodes.length == 0`.)

If you also want `<p> </p>` to be considered empty (note that there's a space there), you need to handle the text node with whitespace in it:

```
if (!theElement.firstChild ||
    (theElement.firstChild.nodeType === 3 &&
     theElement.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === ""
    )
   ) {
    // It's empty
}
```

(`nodeType` 3 is a text node. `trim` trims whitespace from strings. You may need a polyfill on obsolete browsers.)

Examples:

```js
test("ex1");
test("ex2");
test("ex3");
test("ex4");

function simpleEmpty(theElement) {
  return !theElement.firstChild;
}

function emptyHandlingWhitespace(theElement) {
  return !theElement.firstChild ||
         (theElement.firstChild.nodeType === 3 && theElement.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === "");
}

function test(id) {
  var theElement = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(id, simpleEmpty(theElement), emptyHandlingWhitespace(theElement));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<p id="ex1"></p>
<p id="ex2"> </p>
<p id="ex3">test</p>
<p id="ex4"><strong>test</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, about the ! TheElement.firstChild , I think the element is the reference I get from document.getElementByID, but firstChild, what is it? Is value, or what?

Comment: @alexhang: `firstChild` is the name of a predefined property on elements which is a reference to the first node they contain. `<p>xxx</p>` contains a single text node, for instance, whose value is `"xxx"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `innerHTML` property:

```js
function checkIfContainsText(el) {
  return el.innerHTML === '' ? false : true;
}

console.log(checkIfContainsText(document.getElementById('p1')));
console.log(checkIfContainsText(document.getElementById('p2')))
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2">aaa</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Note that when you access `innerHTML`, you're asking the browser to do potentially a fair amount of work: It has to traverse all of the child nodes of the element (and their children, and their children's children) building up a string to return to your JavaScript code. It's unnecessaryily expensive.